# Artifactory 403 Anonymous Access

Tags: apache, tomcat, artifactory, http-status-code-403, ajp

I'm running Artifactory 3.9.2 behind Apache (no auth) using ajp.  The UI works just fine but when I try to access an artifact in this repos or list a directory (http://ziath.com/artifactory/libs-release/) I get a 403 back.  The 000-default file is below:

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyPass  /xxx ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/xxx
    ProxyPassReverse /xxx ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/xxx

    ProxyPass /yyy ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/yyy
    ProxyPassReverse /yyy ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/yyy

    ProxyPass /zzz ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/zzz
    ProxyPassReverse /zzz ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/zzz

    ProxyPass /artifactory ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/artifactory
    ProxyPassReverse /artifactory ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/artifactory
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /artifactory /repository

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

The x/y/z lines are other applications which are passing through just fine.  Looking at the logs I can see the apache request coming in but the only artifactory log entry I can see is in request.log:

```
20170626192333|262|REQUEST|217.33.228.150|anonymous|GET|/libs-release/|HTTP/1.0|
200|0
```

Interestingly when I put in a 'bad; repos (http://ziath.com/artifactory/libs-releasexx/) I get a response:

```
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "/artifactory/libs-releasexx/"
  } ]
}
```

Also the log message appears in artifactory.log:

```
2017-06-26 19:21:54,726 [TP-Processor7] [WARN ] (o.a.w.s.RequestUtils:132) - Request /libs-releasexx/ should be a repo request and does not match any repo key
```

So it really looks like artifactory is accepting a request but then giving me a 403 back though I cannot find any logs past the request.log entry.

Needless to say; it's 20:30 and I'm stuck - does anyone have any advice for me please?

BTW; I tried Artifactory 5.1.4 but I need to run in my own tomcat instance (not a dedicated one for artifactory) and when I tried 5.1.4 it repeatedly kept saying it could not connect to the derby instance - this was even when I tried to make a clean install.

Thanks; in advance for your help.

- ADDENDUM - 
  On advice I went to the local box and used curl to get the details; the command

  curl -vv http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release

gives the response of

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /artifactory/libs-release HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Artifactory/3.9.2
< X-Artifactory-Id: 0e44c1983dacd590:4572b75b:15ce5fb3a3f:-8000
< Location: http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release/
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 13:25:06 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

We know that curl works because if you put in the wrong repository address you get:

```
curl -vv http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-releasexx
```

returns

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /artifactory/libs-releasexx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: Artifactory/3.9.2
< X-Artifactory-Id: 0e44c1983dacd590:4572b75b:15ce5fb3a3f:-8000
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 92
< Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 13:26:29 GMT
<
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "/artifactory/libs-releasexx"
  } ]
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
}* Closing connection #0
```

If we search by the 'directory' rather than repos name we get:

```
curl -vv http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release/
```

returns

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /artifactory/libs-release/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
>
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Artifactory/3.9.2
< X-Artifactory-Id: 0e44c1983dacd590:4572b75b:15ce5fb3a3f:-8000
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=94DCD54787E6A1A928B7B0C08C66EA8D; Path=/artifactory
< Date: Fri, 30 Jun 2017 13:27:27 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Index of libs-release/</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of libs-release/</h1>
<pre>Name  Last modified      Size</pre>
<hr/>
<pre><a href="com/">com/</a>   05-Oct-2016 12:27    -
</pre>
<hr/>
<address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory/3.9.2 Server at localhost Port 8080</address>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

### Interestingly this seems to give an index of the repos but when this is run through apache we get:

Forbidden

### You don't have permission to access /artifactory/libs-release/ on this server.

So we get a different response on apache than artifactory.

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: If you access Artifactory directly, not via Apache, does everything work fine and you are able to access the repositories?

Comment: I can't do that easily on this box (it is public facing and only has port 80 open) but I do have another box running artifactory 3.8.0 with a very similar setup that works just fine.

Comment: No way to SSH the box and curl Artifactory locally? this should give a good indication whether it is an Apache issue or an Artifactory one.

Comment: good thinking - hold on!

Comment: Yes this is my 'non-working' virtual repos:
neil@ziath:/etc/tomcat6$ curl http://localhost:8080/artifactory/lib-releases
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "/artifactory/lib-releases"
  } ]
}

Comment: This is my 'working' virtual repos:

neil@ziath:/etc/tomcat6$  curl http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release
---NOTHING RETURNED----

So even going localhost with the apache/ajp/tomcat path is giving me nothing back.

Comment: Can you use curl -vv to get the headers. In addition can you try with a / at the end of the URL. Also if you can update the question with the results, it will be easier to read

Comment: Interestingly; when you enter without the trailing slash on a 'working' artifactory it redirects to the trailing slash.  So if, as you suggest we add the trailing slash we get different result with localhost than going through apache.  See question for full details.

Comment: Just to point out on this - I gave up; got a new box and installed everything from scratch on that.

Answer (score 0):

Gave up on this in the end - got a new box and installed that from scratch